# Is there some way to implement the Add trait for any type bounded by a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm reading through the ["Advanced Traits" section of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html) where there's an example of adding two types that are not the same:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Millimeters(u32);
struct Meters(u32);

impl Add<Meters> for Millimeters {
    type Output = Millimeters;

    fn add(self, other: Meters) -> Millimeters {
        Millimeters(self.0 + (other.0 * 1000))
    }
}
```

Suppose that I had a trait that both `Millimeters` and `Meters` implemented which specifies how to turn itself into metres (and assuming `Millimeters` and `Meters` implement this):

```
trait Length {
    fn to_meters(&self) -> Meters;
}
```

Is there some way to write a more generic `Add` trait that looks something like this (which is not valid):

```
impl Add<T: Length> for Millimeters {
    type Output = Meters;

    fn add(&self, other: &T) -> Meters {
        let as_meters = other.to_meters();
        Meters((self.0 / 1000) + (as_meters.0))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, except you've inexplicably put the trait bound in the wrong spot and changed the function signature to references instead of values. Fixing that makes it work:

```
impl<T: Length> Add<T> for Millimeters {
    type Output = Meters;

    fn add(self, other: T) -> Meters {
        let as_meters = other.to_meters();
        Meters((self.0 / 1000) + (as_meters.0))
    }
}
```

I'd use [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) and a `where` clause though:

```
impl<T> Add<T> for Millimeters
where
    T: Into<Meters>,
{
    type Output = Meters;

    fn add(self, other: T) -> Meters {
        let as_meters = other.into();
        Meters((self.0 / 1000) + (as_meters.0))
    }
}
```